# Navbar displays an empty space on the right side

Tags: javascript, html, css, uinavigationbar, responsive

https://codepen.io/Cplay/pen/WNGYezE
A greenie that is trying to code.
When I visit the page on mobile mode there appears empty space on the right side, but when I click on the toggle menu of the navigation-bar, it goes away. Could someone help me with this problem?
I used 3 languages, html css and javascript. And already tried to use overflow-x: hidden;. But I do not know where to place this piece of code.

```
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
/* navigation bar */

nav {
    background: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav-links {
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-links a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 35px;
}
.burger {
    display: none;
}
.burger div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1336px) {
    .nav-links {
        display: flex;
        width: 50%;
        justify-content: space-around;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:1100px) {
    .logo {
        width: 10%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:1100px) {
    .body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 205vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: white;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
@keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px)
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}
.toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}
.toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}
.toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}
p {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 300%;
}

<nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Get the game</a>
            </li>
        </ul><img class="logo" src="logo.png" width="10%">
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>

const navSlide = () => {
     const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
     const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
     const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
            //toggle
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

            //animation
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
            if (link.style.animation){
                link.style.animation = ''
            } else {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5 ease forwards ${index / 7 + 1.5}s`;
            }
        });
        //animation
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

    });

}

navSlide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Every Thing with your code is fine. Just Change some property in the .nav-links.
Copy and replace the following .nav-links into your code. Your white space will go away. Fixed position and right:0 will make it stay on the right side. Also make top:0 instead of 22vh.

```js
const navSlide = () => {
     const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
     const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
     const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
            //toggle
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

            //animation
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
            if (link.style.animation){
                link.style.animation = ''
            } else {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5 ease forwards ${index / 7 + 1.5}s`;
            }
        });
        //animation
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

    });

}

navSlide();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
/* navigation bar */

nav {
    background: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.nav-links {
    width: 30%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-links a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 35px;
}
.burger {
    display: none;
}
.burger div {
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1336px) {
    .nav-links {
        display: flex;
        width: 50%;
        justify-content: space-around;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:1100px) {
    .logo {
        width: 10%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width:1100px) {
    .body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links {
        position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}
@keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px)
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}
.toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}
.toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}
.toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}
p {
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
h1 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li>
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Get the game</a>
            </li>
        </ul><img class="logo" src="logo.png" width="10%">
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

```
@media screen and (max-width:1100px) {
.nav-links {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Anwsers with some suggestion and comments like `I hope it will work` are considered low-quality. An anwser should always be a definite solution. Use the code snippet to show that your solution works. Also explain what you did and why you did it. Otherwise the anwser will be hard to understand or follow. As such it will be hard to reproduce the solution and as such be useless.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for helping out. But when I scroll on mobile mode the toggle disappears pretty weird. I tried overflow but it does not respons.